# VMWare Harbor: How to point your registry to a specific directory to use as datastore

Tags: docker, containers, harbor

I am setting up VMWare Harbor as an image registry (just like a docker trusted registry) and I am not sure where it is currently configured to store images once pushed.

I could not find documentation on how to do this, so my question is:
How would I go about mapping Harbor to store images on a specific directory `(/data01)` that has already had disk space allocated for the images?

Comment: could u pls add version info of Harbor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Harbor uses the standard [docker registry](https://docs.docker.com/registry/) behind the scenes, it just provides a nice UI and interface to use it.

Configuring it depends on how you're deploying Harbor itself. There are [instructions for configuring a storage backend](https://github.com/vmware/harbor/blob/master/docs/installation_guide.md#configuring-storage-backend-optional) in the installation guide. If you have a mountpoint like `/data01` you want to use, it is probably something like this:

```
storage:
  filesystem:
    rootdirectory: /data01
```

See the instructions for your harbor installed method for more information.

Answer (score 0):

In harbor v1.5, it store data more than just for docker registery.
It also store data for it's own ui, adminserver ,etc. in `/data` for default.
But for now harbor did not provide an easy configuration to change the default storage path `/data`.
(not sure if it is doable in v1.6)

So if you really want to change the default storage path,
you may search all the yaml for `/data` and replace it by your new path `/data01`.
Or, you can create `/data` and like up with `/data01`, before you start to run up the Harbor